# Will CodenameOne ever support saving images and / or files to a place users can access outside the app?

Tags: codenameone

I've read a few threads where this is discussed. Shai's response has always been that files can only be read, but not written into shared locations

Perhaps saving other type of files isn't so simple but shouldn't there be an option for saving pictures in CN1?

I haven't seen the Whatsapp Clone code, but if it truly is a clone shouldn't it have the option to share pictures (and possibly files). Or is it a simple text chat that perhaps shares pictures that can never be saved outside the app?

I also read somewhere (6 months ago) that Shai said that this should be a feature of CameraKit. Does this mean that this feature is in development? If so, that would be great. But having an ETA would also be great to align with our own devs

If it isn't being developed, can I at least know if this is something I can develop natively within CN1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We expose the full file system so you can write to any place the native App can write to. Native apps don't have write access to the gallery directory and need to explicitly request it to put a file there. This can be accomplished easily in any external cn1lib (e.g. we could do it in camera kit) but haven't done it for camera kit or the whatsapp clone.

AFAIK there's no RFE open on this feature so I can't even tell you if it's assigned to a specific milestone.